# List not filtering correctly is search string is empty

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript, lodash

I have a list that I'm trying to have filter based on what a user types.  As the user types, it searches the string it's checking against and compares the two, if the string is found, it pushes the object to an array, which then displays the filtered objects information.  The issue I'm having is, when the search field is blank, the original, unaltered array of objects needs to be shown.  Instead, what I'm getting is the last successful returned search.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="in-line filter" id="searchByName" placeholder="Enter a name" (keyup)="filterByName($event.target.value)" />
<study-results-table [originalArray]="originalArray"></study-results-table>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(){
  originalArray = new Array<any>();
  unfiltered = new Array<any>()
}

filterByName(searchString){
    this.filtered = new Array<any>();           
    _.each(this.originalArray, (result) => {
        let name = result.firstName.toLowerCase() +" " +result.lastName.toLowerCase();
        if(patientName.includes(searchString.toLowerCase())){
            this.filtered.push(result);
        }
    })

    if(searchString === ""){
        this.originalArray= this.unfiltered;
    }
    this.originalArray= this.filtered;
}
```

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the array's `filter` function? You can simplify the code to the following:

```
filterByName(searchString){
    if(searchString.trim().length==0){
        this.originalArray = this.unfiltered;
        return;
    };
    this.originalArray = this.unfiltered.filter( (result)=>{
        let name = result.firstName.toLowerCase() +" " +result.lastName.toLowerCase();
        return (name.includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));
    });
}
```

Comment: I switched it to filter right after I posted the question, but noticed I was running into another issue when I was deleting characters and that's because I need to be looping through an immutable array rather than the changed one like you show in your answer.